# Mule ESB - How to get MimeMessage instead of MimeBodyPart?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, esb, mule, mime-message

I'm trying to get the FROM email address in Mule ESB.
I'm getting the retrieved object as MimeBodyPart, I'd like to have MimeMessage instead. How to do this?

Any solution - either in Mule or Java is welcome.

The Mule config part for inbound end-point is as below -

```
<inbound>
    <pop3s:inbound-endpoint user="xxx%40gmail.com" password="xxx" host="pop.gmail.com"/>
</inbound>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is this -

```
MimeBodyPart obj;
MimeMultipart top = (MimeMultipart) obj.getParent();
MimeMessage msg = (MimeMessage) top.getParent();
```

The initial obj is provided by Mule.